# Array jave data object with {} and i need to ignore it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array with data where i need to sum all the values for each key and get a total. Then I create a new array with each key and total. But I'm facing an issue when I get empty data and I need to ignore when I have {} inside my array object. I'm facing some issues doing this and to resolve this I was trying to validate if my data is different than {}

```
var data = [{"data":{"since":1500896035232,"passerby":212,"live":159,"accesspoints":37,"associated":122,"knownvendor":139,"knownvendorinternal":109,"knownvendorcommon":107,"proberequest":75}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}}];


var array=[];
var labels = [9];
var total = [9];

//iniciar a zero todos os elementos do array

for(var x=0; x<9;x++){
 total[x] = 0;
}

var live=0, associated=0, ap=0, others=0;
var cas=0, official=0, common=0;

console.log("live data ",data[2]);

for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i]!={}){
        for(var j=1;j<9;j++){   
            switch(j){
                case 1:
                    labels[j-1] = "passerby";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    labels[j-1]="live";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    live=total[j-1];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    labels[j-1]="accesspoints";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    ap=total[j-1];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    labels[j-1]="associated";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    associated=total[j-1];              
                    break;
                case 5:
                    labels[j-1]="knownvendor";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    official=total[j-1];

                    break;
                case 6:
                    labels[j-1]="knownvendorinternal";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    cas=total[j-1];             
                    break;
                case 7:
                    labels[j-1]="knownvendorcommon";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    common=total[j-1];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    labels[j-1]="proberequest";
                    total[j-1] += data[i]['data'][labels[j-1]];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<labels.length; i++){
    var obj = {
       "label": labels[i],
       "value": total[i]
    };
    array.push(obj);
}

others1 = live - ap - associated;

var othersObj = {
    "label": "others",
    "value": others1
};

array.push(othersObj);

console.log("array ---> ", array);
console.log("data size ---> ", data.length);


console.log("-------------------------------");


console.log("live ---> ", live);
console.log("ap ---> ", ap);
console.log("associated ---> ", associated);
console.log("others ---> ", others1);

console.log("-------------------------------");

others2 = live-cas-official;

console.log("cas --> ",cas);
console.log("official --> ",official);
console.log("common --> ",common);
console.log("others ---> ", others2);
```

Logs

```
live data  { data: {} }
array --->  [ { label: 'passerby', value: NaN },
  { label: 'live', value: NaN },
  { label: 'accesspoints', value: NaN },
  { label: 'associated', value: NaN },
  { label: 'knownvendor', value: NaN },
  { label: 'knownvendorinternal', value: NaN },
  { label: 'knownvendorcommon', value: NaN },
  { label: 'proberequest', value: NaN },
  { label: 'others', value: NaN } ]
data size --->  20
-------------------------------
live --->  NaN
ap --->  NaN
associated --->  NaN
others --->  NaN
-------------------------------
cas -->  NaN
official -->  NaN
common -->  NaN
others --->  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `reduce()` to sum the values by key, then map the resulting object's keys to get the desired data structure.

```js
let data = [{"data":{"since":1500896035232,"passerby":212,"live":159,"accesspoints":37,"associated":122,"knownvendor":139,"knownvendorinternal":109,"knownvendorcommon":107,"proberequest":75}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}},{"data":{}}];
let r = data.reduce((a,b) => {
  Object.keys(b.data).forEach(v => {
    if (v === 'since') return;
    a[v] = a[v] ? a[v] : 0;
    a[v] += parseInt(b.data[v]) || 0;
  });
  return a;
}, {});
let res = Object.keys(r).map(v => ({
  label: v,
  value: r[v]
}));
console.log(res);
```